# Get program RAM usage (in MB) at runtime (Windows 10)

Tags: c++

Is there an easy way to find out how much RAM (in MB) does my program use after different operations (large matrix manipulation)? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: That's OS specific.

Comment: oh I am sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: I think you are looking for profiling. You should have one with [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019) or can use something like Intel VTune.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard (read e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) don't mention RAM, so your question is operating system specific. Also, on most OSes a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) runs in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), and two different processes might share some common (either virtual, or physical) memory. Read a [good textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

During execution, some pages might be swapped out to the swap area on your disk.

Hence, the very notion of RAM usage is approximate and changes with time. Read about [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) and [page faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) and [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit).

But on Linux, you could use the `/proc/`  file system. Read [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) . Your program would access `/proc/self/maps`

For Windows, read the WinAPI documentation. You probably want [virtual memory functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/virtual-memory-functions) and [memory management functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-management-functions).

You might redefine your `::operator new` and/or use libraries like [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/). With GPGPUs and [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) things become even more complex. Some compilers have [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC) extensions facilitating these.

Comment: Yeah I found out it's OS specific and edited the question. I am using Windows 10.